# How can I incremently count and sum values of a column based on condition in SQL?

Tags: python, sql

I think I need to compare the current value of the ID column with the next value and then sum the values from count column. The second table is the expected table. I was able to achieve this in python but I need to do this in SQL.

This is my current table:

| ID | SEQ | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 122 | 1 | 0 |
| 122 | 2 | 0 |
| 122 | 3 | 0 |
| 122 | 4 | 1 |
| 122 | 5 | 0 |
| 122 | 6 | 0 |
| 122 | 7 | 1 |
| 122 | 8 | 0 |
| 122 | 9 | 1 |
| 122 | 10 | 0 |
| 122 | 11 | 0 |
| 177 | 1 | 0 |
| 177 | 2 | 1 |
| 177 | 3 | 0 |
| 177 | 4 | 0 |
| 177 | 5 | 1 |
| 177 | 6 | 0 |
| 177 | 7 | 0 |
| 177 | 8 | 0 |

This is what I want to achieve:

| ID | SEQ | MARK | COUNT_SEQ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 122 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 122 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 122 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 122 | 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 122 | 5 | 0 | 1 |
| 122 | 6 | 0 | 1 |
| 122 | 7 | 1 | 2 |
| 122 | 8 | 0 | 2 |
| 122 | 9 | 1 | 3 |
| 122 | 10 | 0 | 3 |
| 122 | 11 | 0 | 3 |
| 177 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 177 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 177 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 177 | 4 | 0 | 1 |
| 177 | 5 | 1 | 2 |
| 177 | 6 | 0 | 2 |
| 177 | 7 | 0 | 2 |
| 177 | 8 | 0 | 2 |

Comment: Are rows 13 & 14 correct?
177 2 1  177 2 0 0
177 3 0  177 3 1 1

Answer (score 0):

I tried using a self join, does this answer your question?

```
 SELECT t.id, t.seq, SUM(t.MARK) AS COUNT_SEQ FROM(
 SELECT a.id, a.seq, b.count as MARK FROM table1 a
 RIGHT JOIN table1 b on a.id = b.id and b.seq <= a.seq) as t
 GROUP BY t.id, t.seq
```

[db fiddle link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vLD9W8R1taS4ecLxyg9iK3/3)

Answer (score 0):

As we can see from the output table, the `Mark` column will be the same as the `Count` column from the input table, and the `COUNT_SEQ` column should contain the sum of the `Count` column for all rows above the current row including the current row.

So we can simplify the problem by "finding the sum of all rows above the current row".

Check the following SQL query (tested on `MS SQL Server 2019`, `SQLite 3.3` and `PostgreSQL v13`):

```
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT id,seq,count,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS row
FROM Test 
) 
SELECT a.id,a.seq,a.count as Mark ,SUM(b.count) as COUNT_SEQ
    FROM cte a
    INNER JOIN cte b ON a.row >=b.row and a.id=b.id
GROUP BY a.id,a.seq,a.count
order by a.id,a.seq
```

See the result from [HERE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fAUkZCCcXm8Fw51Z833zXT/0).

Answer (score 0):

Check this?

```
select 
  id, 
  seq, 
  mark, 
  sum(mark) over(
    partition by id 
    order by 
      seq
  ) as count_seq 
from 
  t1;
```

https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/nkbgddeaajpwjft426qhniyqf